# Delphi : differant image sizes in listview

Tags: delphi, listview

is it possible to add differant image sizes in the same listview

for example

adding item with 32pxl icon and 24pxl subitems

thanks in advance

Comment: Sure. If that wouldn't be able in a standard way (by using binded image lists), you can still draw whatever you want by yourself (in some of the custom draw events).

Comment: my app always changing the subimages every seconds also i use custom items sorting code which clearing subitems
 ,,, is custom draw will be useful in my case ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An image list control is constrained such that all images have the same dimensions. I'm assuming that you are using the `vsReport` view mode, which means that your images will come from the image list attached to the `SmallImages` property. And so they must all be the same size.

The constraints are not imposed by Delphi. They are a straight reflection of the underlying Windows control. Windows image lists are implemented in a way that means all images are the same size. They are implemented as a rectangular bitmap that contains all images one after the other. And the various images properties of Delphi's list view control simply wrap the common control functionality – see [`LVM_SETIMAGELIST`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761178.aspx).

You could place your 24px images into 32px images with a transparent area to increase the size from 24px to 32px. If that doesn't do what you need, then you'll need to paint the images yourself.

Comment: thats exactly what i'm doing now but my problem with it that i have many subitems each subitem contain only icon without text ,,, so i need to make the columns 24pxl width ,,, its ok with windows 7 but in windows XP i dunno why the image always stretching ! (i tried PNG and BMP-32bit images)